# Get best seller products

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection, best-seller

I'm trying to get in the home page 12 bestseller products with this code:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                                                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                                    ->addOrderedQty()
                                                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                                                    ->addStoreFilter($storeId) 
                                                    ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
```

The problem is that with this code I have the bestsellers of all stores.

The parameter **->setStoreId()** and **->addStoreFilter** don't work.

Any idea?

**EDIT**

With the code of Rakesh Donga get the next list:
[image]

These products have the status "disabled" in backend.

In the backend go to Reports -> Products -> Products ordered and get this products:

[image]

Comment: store id how to get it?

Comment: with this: $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

Comment: here another store products coming?

Comment: No, return the correct id but the collection of products are about all the websites

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Need override the file:

> "Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php"

Add the next function at the end of the file:

```
 public function addWebsiteFilterPurchased()
{

    $storeId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('store');
    if($storeId == null){
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    }

    $this->getSelect()->where('order_items.store_id IN (?)', (array)$storeId);

    return $this;
}
```

And use it:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                                                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                                    ->addOrderedQty()
                                                    ->addWebsiteFilterPurchased()
                                                    ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using following code:

**Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Collection**

```
/**
 * Add store restrictions to product collection
 *
 * @param  array $storeIds
 * @param  array $websiteIds
 * @return Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
 */
public function addStoreRestrictions($storeIds, $websiteIds)
{
    if (!is_array($storeIds)) {
        $storeIds = array($storeIds);
    }
    if (!is_array($websiteIds)) {
        $websiteIds = array($websiteIds);
    }

    $filters = $this->_productLimitationFilters;
    if (isset($filters['store_id'])) {
        if (!in_array($filters['store_id'], $storeIds)) {
            $this->addStoreFilter($filters['store_id']);
        } else {
            $this->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreId());
        }
    } else {
        $this->addWebsiteFilter($websiteIds);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

So your case:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                                                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                                    ->addOrderedQty()
                                                    ->addStoreRestrictions([$storeId], [$websiteIds])
                                                    ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
```

Comment: I put this: ->addStoreRestrictions([$storeId], [Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId)->getWebsiteId()]) and return an incorrect list